# How to copy a data stream (non-A/V) from input MP4 file from a DJI drone with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, mp4

I've got an `MP4` video file captured by DJI drone. The file contains the **video stream** (H.264) and also two **data streams** of unknown format. I would like to convert the video from `h.264` to `h.265` and also save both of the included data streams. Unfortunately, I cannot force [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to copy the data streams across from the input file into the output file.

Here is the mp4 file (`ffprobe DJI_0019.MP4`) info:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x5631004c2730] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'DJI_0019.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : replaced_timestamp
    encoder         : DJIMavic3
  Duration: 00:01:05.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128915 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 127648 kb/s, 29.41 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : replaced_timestamp
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Data: none (djmd / 0x646D6A64), 13 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : replaced_timestamp
      handler_name    : DJI meta
  Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (dbgi / 0x69676264), 1190 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : replaced_timestamp
      handler_name    : DJI dbgi
  Stream #0:3: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 1
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

I tried the command below:

```
ffmpeg -i DJI_0019.MP4 -map 0 -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -c:d copy -copy_unknown DJI_0019.v2.MP4
```

The command fails with the following error. The output file is empty.

```
[mp4 @ 0x556d0180ced0] Could not find tag for codec none in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

Note that for "-c:d" option I tried different suggested values, none of them succeeded:

```
copy
none
bin
bin_data
data
null
file
```

In the meantime an attempt to save the data streams to separate files succeeds for the both of them with the commands:

```
ffmpeg -i DJI_0019.MP4 -map 0:d:0 -c copy -copy_unknown -f data DJI_0019.data0.bin
```

```
ffmpeg -i DJI_0019.MP4 -map 0:d:1 -c copy -copy_unknown -f data DJI_0019.data1.bin
```

**Question:**

##### How to force FFmpeg to copy the data streams from input to output?

This is the ffmpeg's info:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.3.0 (Gentoo 11.3.0 p5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 
--docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg-4.4.3/html --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared 
--cc=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc --cxx=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ --ar=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar 
--nm=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-nm --strip=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-strip 
--ranlib=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ranlib --pkg-config=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-pkg-config 
--optflags='-O2 -pipe -march=native' --disable-static --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample 
--disable-stripping --disable-optimizations --disable-libcelt --disable-indev=oss 
--disable-indev=jack --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=oss --disable-outdev=sndio 
--enable-nonfree --enable-bzlib --disable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-debug --disable-gcrypt 
--enable-gnutls --disable-gmp --enable-gpl --disable-hardcoded-tables --enable-iconv 
--disable-libxml2 --disable-lzma --enable-network --disable-opencl --disable-openssl 
--enable-postproc --disable-libsmbclient --enable-ffplay --enable-sdl2 --disable-vaapi 
--disable-vdpau --disable-vulkan --enable-xlib --enable-libxcb --enable-libxcb-shm 
--enable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-zlib --enable-libcdio --disable-libiec61883 
--disable-libdc1394 --enable-libcaca --disable-openal --disable-opengl --enable-libv4l2 
--disable-libpulse --disable-libdrm --disable-libjack --disable-libopencore-amrwb 
--disable-libopencore-amrnb --disable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac 
--disable-libopenjpeg --disable-libbluray --disable-libgme --disable-libgsm 
--disable-libaribb24 --disable-mmal --disable-libmodplug --disable-libopus 
--disable-libilbc --disable-librtmp --disable-libssh --disable-libspeex --disable-libsrt 
--disable-librsvg --disable-ffnvcodec --disable-libvorbis --disable-libvpx --disable-libzvbi 
--disable-appkit --disable-libbs2b --disable-chromaprint --disable-cuda-llvm 
--disable-libflite --disable-frei0r --disable-libvmaf --disable-libfribidi 
--disable-fontconfig --disable-ladspa --enable-libass --disable-libtesseract 
--disable-lv2 --disable-libfreetype --disable-libvidstab --disable-librubberband 
--disable-libzmq --disable-libzimg --disable-libsoxr --enable-pthreads --disable-amf 
--disable-libvo-amrwbenc --disable-libkvazaar --disable-libaom --enable-libmp3lame 
--disable-libopenh264 --disable-librav1e --disable-libsnappy --disable-libsvtav1 
--disable-libtheora --disable-libtwolame --disable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 
--enable-libxvid --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-armv6t2 --disable-neon 
--disable-vfp --disable-vfpv3 --disable-armv8 --disable-mipsdsp --disable-mipsdspr2 
--disable-mipsfpu --disable-altivec --disable-vsx --disable-power8 --disable-amd3dnow 
--disable-amd3dnowext --disable-aesni --disable-avx --disable-avx2 --disable-fma3 
--disable-fma4 --disable-sse3 --disable-ssse3 --disable-sse4 --disable-sse42 --disable-xop 
--cpu=host --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --enable-manpages
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems mp4 container doesn't accept data stream.

To convert your video with data streams, you can use the mpeg-ts container which accepts data streams.

To record in an mpeg-ts container:
`ffmpeg -i <input> -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts record.ts`

And then to read / to extract the data content:
`ffmpeg -i record.ts -map 0:1 -c copy -f data data1.txt`
and
`ffmpeg -i record.ts -map 0:2 -c copy -f data data2.txt`

Comment: Converting to the `mpeg-ts` container works. I was able to copy the data streams along with the video one. **However, it is not clear, why `mp4` container cannot indlude data streams?** Initially, the `mp4` file created by drone contained two data streams.

Comment: @darkshine I have no info on "DJI dbgi" stream and what they contain. Is it something like [hint tracks](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-13)? Is it a DJI proprietary format? I have no idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Also had this issue with Sony Videos (h264 and h265 encoded files, stemming from ILCE-7M4): MP4s containing Realtime Metadata (rtmd) which ffmpeg did not allow to copy directly (being super strict). MP4Box does this for you, so you do not necessarily need to "move" your container to MOV or M4V.
In the following example I do a 2-pass conversion using Apple's AAC Encoder and a specific bitrate (!= CRF):

```
ffmpeg -y -i "${INPUTFILE}" -c:v libx265 -b:v 35000k -x265-params pass=1 -an -f null /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i "${INPUTFILE}" -c:v libx265 -b:v 35000k -x265-params pass=2 -c:a aac_at -b:a 192k -movflags use_metadata_tags+faststart -map_metadata 0 -tag:v hvc1 "${OUTPUTFILE}"
MP4Box -add ${INPUTFILE}#3 ${OUTPUTFILE}
MP4Box -dump-xml ${INPUTFILE}.xml ${INPUTFILE}
MP4Box -set-meta META -set-xml ${INPUTFILE}.xml ${OUTPUTFILE}
```